# json into dataframe using R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, data.table

I tried to merge the data but could not get desired results this is just a slice of thousand of records. so far tried

```
l <- fromJSON(data$X9, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
df <- do.call(cbind, l)
```

but could not get desired results I want column 1-8 and column 9 (json) spread wide data (column name, value only) in a single row

```
data <- structure(list(X1 = 3079, X2 = 15112, X3 = 0, X4 = 0, X5 = NA,X6 = NA, X7 = 0, X8 = 0, X9 = "\n{\r\n\"1\":{\"name\":\"Program Type\",\"value\":\"Internship\",\"value_raw\":\"Internship\",\"id\":1,\"type\":\"select\"},\r\n\"3\":{\"name\":\"Field Of Study\",\"value\":\"Medical Practitioner - Internship\",\"value_raw\":\"Medical Practitioner - Internship\",\"id\":3,\"type\":\"select\"},\r\n\"488\":{\"name\":\"Studied in South Africa?\",\"value\":\"Yes\",\"value_raw\":\"Yes\",\"id\":488,\"type\":\"select\"},\"732\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 8 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":732,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"731\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 9 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":731,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"730\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 10 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":730,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"729\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 11 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":729,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"728\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 12 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":728,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"727\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 13 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":727,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"726\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 14 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":726,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"725\":{\"name\":\"Facility Group 15 - WC\",\"value\":\"\",\"value_raw\":\"\",\"id\":725,\"type\":\"select\",\"visible\":false},\"868\":{\"name\":\"Declarations and Consent\",\"value\":\"I declare that the information entered in this application form and any attached\\/uploaded documents are valid and true\\nI consent\",\"id\":868,\"type\":\"checkbox\"}}",X10 = NA, X11 = structure(1696441392, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), X12 = structure(1696441392, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), X13 = NA, X14 = "Mozilla",X15 = "9-ae45-6"), row.names = c(NA,-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

As suggested in comments

```
    data[2,] <- data[1,]
dt <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data$X9[1]) |> rbindlist(idcol="ID", fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
dt <- dt[,2:3]
dt <- as.data.frame(t(dt))
colnames(dt) <-  dt[1, ]
dt = dt[-1, ]
data <- data[,c(1:8,10:15)]
final <- cbind(data,dt)
```

the final output I'm looking by reducing the steps and without loop etc

Comment: The expected output is unclear to me.

Comment: Are we supposed to infer that `X9` in your structure is the raw json, or is there something else for your `l`?

Comment: Looking at your data, ... to me it looks like it really should be _long_ format, not wide as you say by requesting a single row.

Comment: For instance, `jsonlite::fromJSON(...$X9) |> rbindlist(idcol="ID", fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)` produces a legitimate-looking frame to me.

Comment: data <- has 15 columns I need first 8 columns and 9th column which is structured json data, need to read that wide data and attached to the row of 1-8 columns .... required just name and value something like this but on thousand rows .... l <- fromJSON(data$X9, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
df <- do.call(cbind, l)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
dt <- data.frame(sapply(df,c))
row.names(df) <- NULL
df <- df[1:2,]
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <-  df[1, ]
df = df[-1, ]
data <- data[1:8]
final <- cbind(data,df)
< sorry for bad format

Comment: I shared only one row in with fewer columns in > data < actually it contains thousand rows with 400 + columns

Comment: if people are proposing answers which wouldn't work with your actual dataset, please update the sample dataset so that kind of thing doesn't happen again

Comment: I understand but I wish I could create more perfect example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# repeat the first row for demonstration of multi-row operation
data <- data[c(1,1),]
newdt <- lapply(data$X9, jsonlite::fromJSON) |>
  lapply(function(z)
    dcast(rbindlist(
      lapply(z, `[`, c("name", "value")))[, ign:=1],
      ign ~ name, value.var = "value")[,-1]) |>
  rbindlist()
cbind(data[,-9], newdt)
#       X1    X2    X3    X4     X5     X6    X7    X8    X10                 X11                 X12    X13     X14      X15                Declarations and Consent Facility Group 10 - WC Facility Group 11 - WC Facility Group 12 - WC Facility Group 13 - WC Facility Group 14 - WC Facility Group 15 - WC
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <lgcl> <lgcl> <num> <num> <lgcl>              <POSc>              <POSc> <lgcl>  <char>   <char>                                  <char>                 <char>                 <char>                 <char>                 <char>                 <char>                 <char>
# 1:  3079 15112     0     0     NA     NA     0     0     NA 2023-10-04 17:43:12 2023-10-04 17:43:12     NA Mozilla 9-ae45-6 I declare that the information enter...                                                                                                                                          
# 2:  3079 15112     0     0     NA     NA     0     0     NA 2023-10-04 17:43:12 2023-10-04 17:43:12     NA Mozilla 9-ae45-6 I declare that the information enter...                                                                                                                                          
# 5 variables not shown: [Facility Group 8 - WC <char>, Facility Group 9 - WC <char>, Field Of Study <char>, Program Type <char>, Studied in South Africa? <char>]
```